# If third number is 1 then insert text X

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have variating numeric entries (SF123456, SF142365, ...). Every number of the numeric entries corresponds to a specific code. For each number of each entry I need to enter on a separate cell the corresponding code (download here example sheet: www.nivpat.com/Example.zip) How can I create an automatic function as I have thousands of entries to divide into codes... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alright. What I did to solve this one is this:

- Remove the '=' sign in your match table to be able to do a `VLOOKUP` on it;
- Add the position of the digit you want to look up in the row 9 right above the headings. You might want to hide this row for cleaner presentation;
- I used the following formula in the cells to extract the values:

`=VLOOKUP(VALUE(MID($A11, B$9, 1)), $A$2:$B$7, 2, 0)`

The `VLOOKUP` does the lookup on your table in `A2:B7`. The `MID()` extract exactly one character beginning with the character specified in `B9` (in this case it would be 3). And the `VALUE()` converts the text string to a number to be able to do a match with the table above.

The only thing you now have to do is to drag your formulas and it's working !